# Error in using "caption" package: "caption: For a successful cooperation we need at least version(caption) is available. }{}"

Tags: captions

I need to use the "caption" package. I downloaded it from CTAN and copied the file "caption.dtx" in my folder. When I compile the code, I get the following error:

```
caption: For a successful cooperation we need at least version(caption) is available. }{}
```

What does it mean? it doesn't even tell what version it asks...

Comment: That's clearly a wrong installation, I would say. Rather let your TeX distribution package manager install such a package or, if really needed, you most probably have to say `latex caption.dtx`, but this should be the last hammer to apply ;-)

Comment: A simpler solution consists in unzipping `caption.tds.zip` at the `root` of a local TeXMF directory, and running `texhash`. You'll find it in the `install` directory on CTAN, e.g. `ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/install/macros/latex/contrib/`.